# What is a 'character set' in this context?

Tags: c

I was wondering what a 'character set' is/means in the following context?

> C, remember, uses the term byte to denote the size used to
> hold a system’s character set, so a C byte could be 8 bits, 9 bits, 16 bits, or some other value.

Comment: This means the list of characters that are used on that machine. For example, all the latin letters (A through Z), numbers (0 through 9), and symbols like parenthesis, brackets, and so on. We mostly use ASCII, which is 7-bits, but C garantees that char is at least 8-bits long. If the local machine charset was UCS, for example, the byte would have 16-bits, because it is a set much larger than ASCII.

Comment: A byte is a type that can hold one character, not a set of anything. All characters that a byte can potentially hold form the system's character set.

Comment: I understand. My thanks to both of you.

Comment: See the [online draft of the C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 5.2.1, for the official definition.

Comment: This is quote is beyond inaccurate, by the way. For instance, on Windows, a `char` is 8 bits, but Windows' character set has been Unicode (since Windows NT 3.1, first released in 1993), which has codepoints of up to 21 bits. In early versions of Unicode, UCS-2 was sufficient, which needs up 16 bits per codepoint. Note that I keep mentioning "codepoint", because the idea of a "character" in the context of Unicode [is complicated at best](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf#G2212).

Comment: Also, a "byte" is not about text encoding. A byte is the smallest addressable unit of data in a system. For systems based on x86, ARM, or MIPS processors, this is a unit of 8 bits.

Comment: @Rhymoid So the definition of a byte is dependent on the processor?

Comment: Exactly. The reason that most people still talk about "bytes" when they mean "octets" (i.e. units of eight bits) is nine parts ignorance and one part tradition.

Comment: @Rhymoid Very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: I now realise that my comments are a bit misleading. Aside from blaming myself, I blame the C standard of using a very strange interpretation of the term. See my answer for a better overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote displays a poor understanding of terminology. A "character set" is a collection of characters. Rather, a byte-as-understood-by-C is defined to be large enough to contain a character from the basic character set, which is implementation-defined. Usually, "byte" (in the context of C) and `char` are synonymous.

---

A byte, in the general sense, is the smallest addressable unit of data storage. Its size therefore depends on whatever platform or processor you're talking about. For many systems, a byte is eight bits in size (a unit also known as "octet"). This is why "byte" is often used to mean "octet". In the general sense, "bytes" are not at all defined based on text encoding.

On the other hand, in C, bytes *are* defined based on text encoding. What a byte is ***in the context of C*** is defined by [section 3.5 of N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=22) (the final C11 draft) as

> addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment

This is commonly understood as being equivalent to the type `char`. Section 6.2.5 clause 3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=40) says:

> An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char` object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative.

(This, however, does not explicitly say that a `char` is the same thing as a C byte. Also, a `char` must at least be 8 bits, because `CHAR_BIT` is at least `8`, and whether `char` is signed or not depends on the implementation.)

C makes a distinction between an implementation's *basic character set* and its *extended character set*; these are defined in defined in [section 5.2.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=40). Note that C doesn't have anything named "a system's character set". The basic character set must at least include the following characters:

- all uppercase and lowercase letters of the "Latin alphabet" (as used in English, without diacritics),
- the (Arabic) decimal digits (as written in English),
- the 29 graphic characters used in C (such as `!`, `"`, `#`), and
- a few control characters (such as space and `'\0'`).

This is only half the truth, by the way; C also distinguishes between a "source character set" and an "execution character set". This begs the question: is C's idea of a byte defined by the basic source character set, or by the basic execution character set? I have not found an answer to that question in the standard draft.